# алгоритм выбора оптимального проекта

Tags: алгоритм, project

Я работаю в большой компании, но если рассмотреть её с точки зрения IT компании, то она начинающая в этом деле (скажем так).

Меня интересует есть ли какая-то теория или практические алгоритмы выбора проекта. Предположим, есть 2 отдела которые пришли в IT отдел и попросили реализовать проект под бизнес процесс.

Например есть проект А и В.
Проект А стоит 100 тыс.$ на рынке.
Проект В стоит 500 тыс.$ на рынке.

В бизнесс-процессе проекта А участвуют 5 отделов.
В бизнесс-процессе проекта В участвуют2 отдела.

На проект А необходимо 4 разработчика
На проект В необходимо 10 разработчиков

И по выше указанным параметрам (предположительным) реализовать какой-то алгорим для принятия решения.
что бы выбор проекта был основан на каких-то расчётах и его выбор можно было аргументировать

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, метку "алгоритм". Как никак, она тоже относится к вопросу.

Comment: это что то вроде экспертной системы, наверно машинное обучение тут надо подключать или методы оптимизации или все намного проще и можно банально ифами выбрать необходимый проект взвешивая их и добавляя плюсы минусы за каждый из аспектов

Comment: думаю ифами это исключительно как запасной вариант.

Answer (score 2):

Алгоритм лучше выводить с упором на выгоду компании. Вы упомянули три критерия: стоимость проекта. сколько отделов захватывает и количество разработчиков. Также, есть параметр времени. Вычитаем из бюджета з/п разработчикам. Получаем конечную выгоду компании. Но, также, нужно учитывать количество задействованных отделов, ведь если их будет много, то не останется места для других проектов. Аналогично со временем.

Вывод: алгоритм должен находить проект который наиболее дорог, у которого минимально количество отделов и сотрудников для его выполнения.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ! однако смутило почему кол-во отделов должно быть минимальным. наверное меня не правильно поняли, я сейчас внесу правку в изначальный вопрос. Имелось ввиду что в бизнесс-процессе принимают участие  5 или 2 отдела, что говорит о том , что проект весьма важен так как многие в нём принимают участие

Comment: Извините, произошло действительно недопонимание. Я понял так, что чем больше отделов затронуто, тем больше он энергозатратен, тем меньше выгода для компании. Однако Ваша точка зрения тоже вполне верна.

Comment: А есть ли теории такого алгоритма ? допустим я знаю метод принятия решения "дерево решений" , но можно ли его применять в данном случае ? И возможно есть более специализированный алгоритм для IT проектов ?

Comment: Да, здесь лучше будет применять дерево для параметров. Если какой-либо параметр соответствует, то он становится более приоритетным, и уже после него проверяются оставшиеся. То есть, можно ввести параметр как коэффициент важности. Сначала проверяются просто 4 параметра и определяется наиболее важный. К примеру, стоимость. +10 к КВ. Затем после стоимости проверяется кол-во отделов. Допустим, их затронуто 5, поэтому КВ + 5. Разработчиков же занято к примеру, 10. А нормой является 5 по каким-либо причинам. Поэтому кВ -5. В конечном итоге, КВ будет 10.

Answer (score 1):

Это задача моделирования. Ошибочо считать что существует такой алгоритм для этой задачи, это эквивалентно играм на бирже или в покер. Самое максимальное что придумало человечество это рынок. Так вот рынок - это купи дешевле продай дороже.
А рынок вещь очень сложная там очень много факторов и рисков. Пример работы на перспективу нужно заманить богатого клиента пусть и на не очень выгодный проект. Пример "срубить бабла" берёшь самый дорогой и не важно сделаешь его или нет. Это проект и нет гарантий что он выстрелит.

а так в нормальной ситуации

1. Изучение и оценка проекта (сможем, не сможем).
2. Изучение и оценка клиента (сможем сдать, не сможем сдать).
3. Оценка прибыли с учетом всех за и против

Comment: Прочитав Ваш ответ, я заметил что он больше нацелен на внешнего клиента. То есть на заказчика , а мой вопрос больше нацелен на внутреннего клиента, то есть на смежные отделы. Но спасибо за Ваш ответ, он так же имеет ценность.

Comment: а Если посмотреть с точки зрения заказчик - владелец компании? И вы должны обосновать ваши затраты его средств и сдать ему проект